# IOS Swift 3 UILabels in View don't get rendered correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uilabel

To start some information about my setup: I have a Storyboard with 3 Views and 3 ViewControllers, one attached to each of the Views.

I'm switching the Views from a completion handler of a DataTask (http request) with `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookingSuccess", sender: nil)`. To be able to pass some data I use the prepare function where I assign my ViewModel to the destination Controller.

After that i prepare some UI Stuff in the `ViewDidLoad()` function and assign Values to my Labels in the `ViewWillAppear()` Method.

This works fine, but when the view switches, half of the UI Elements don't show and the button text is somehow also not there. Under some circumstances, which I don't know (most time after just waiting a few seconds or reopen without closing the APP these Elements are suddenly showing up. 
I tried a lot of different things and nothing works. Sometimes a label shown up at the beginning, but I haven't got any Idea why it's not displaying. My IOS Target Version is either IOS 10 or IOS 11.0.1/3

Here are two images of the screens: 
[Directly after switching the View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8kT0.png)

[After waiting about 10 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naCNH.png)

Comment: Make sure `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookingSuccess", sender: nil)` is called on the Main Thread, this sounds like you are doing UI stuff on the background thread

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast answer, I tried with DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookingSuccess", sender: nil)
                        }
But it doesn't worked

Comment: do `async` not `sync`

Comment: It's working, thank you very much!!! Insane @Ladislav

Comment: Ok, will add it as an answer so that others can benefit from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with doing UI work on the background thread. Since you are calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookingSuccess", sender: nil)` from the completion handler of the DataTask and that will be on the background thread so do:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookingSuccess", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: should be `async` or not?